# Serilog - Warnings for missing parameters

Tags: c#, string-formatting, serilog

Just starting using Serilog and already I see log entries in the code where people have modified the output format string and lost a parameter.  It would be nice to have a flag where it logged an extra warning when there are more parameters than there are slots to fill in the format string.  For example:

```
log.Warning("{firstParam:l} {secondParam}", test, test1, test2);
```

Or vice versa:

```
log.Warning("{firstParam:l} {secondParam} {thirdParam} {fourthParam}", test, test1, test2);
```

At least this last one outputs an empty element for fourthParam.  The first one could also output an element like "missing1" : "test2Value".

Or is there a way to get this to happen, but I haven't seen it yet?

Comment: That's not related to Serilog (since it just does a `string.Format`) and you'd have to create your own analyzer (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2017)) if you wanted this

Answer (score 1):

[@Robin Sue's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1245878/suchiman) got you covered with the wonderful [Serilog Analyzer](https://github.com/Suchiman/SerilogAnalyzer).

The other thing is to turn on [the `SelfLog`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog) so you find ones that slip through.

Having said all that, I'm not sure if either mechanism provides a facility for complaining about too many - I'd say that's well worth logging an Issue on the GitHub around to at least discuss the options around.

Comment: can it also warn you if you use `Serilog` with a wrapper?

Comment: @Green the code is a Roslyn analyzer, so it depends on the nature of your wrapping - if you've black boxed it up, the analyzer will have no basis on which to suspect a given set of calls represent Serilog logging statements. The answer is in the repo ...